# convert ExtAudioFileRef type to AudioFileID type in iOS

Tags: ios, audio, types, extaudiofile

I've been using ExtAudioFile Services and I want to use an AudioFile Service which requires an AudioFileID parameter. This parameter corresponds to ExtAudioFileRef used in ExtAudioFile Services. How do I convert from  ExtAudioFileRef type to AudioFileID type?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Just typecast it, it works fine!

`AudioFileID audiofile = (AudioFileID)AudioExt where AudioExt is of type ExtAudioFileRef`

Comment: This may work now, but it is neither documented nor supported by Apple as far as I know.  Sticking with the API supported solution is a better long term approach.

Answer (score 8):

I know this one is old and answered, but I just noticed it and thought I'll leave a correct answer here for future reference

```
AudioFileID audioFile;
UInt32 dataSize = sizeof(AudioFileID);
ExtAudioFileGetProperty(extAudioFile, kExtAudioFileProperty_AudioFile, &dataSize, &audioFile);
```